# java regex split string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that I need to split out and get the production_date value, so in this example I would need the '2013-01-01' and '2014-01-01'.

It may or may not always be in this column but any sugguestions on what the best way would be?

```
where filter_2_id = 20001 and acceptable_flag is true  and production_date  >=  '2013-01-01' AND production_date  <=  '2014-01-01'  AND filter_2_id IN (20000, 20001)  AND filter_1_id IN ( 10000 )  order by tr.test_result_id ASC
```

Comment: Write a regular expression that matches the date, and use `.match()` to find all the matches. Which part of this are you having trouble with? Please show what you tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I'm really not too familiar with writing expressions - I haven't wrote anything yet.

Comment: Then you should read a tutorial, like the one at regular-expression.info. SO is not a substitute for learning how to program.

Comment: ok thank you for your feedback

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code/regex writing request without any description of problem which stops OP from writing it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you :

```
    String s = "where filter_2_id = 20001 and acceptable_flag is true  and production_date  >=  '2013-01-01' AND production_date  <=  '2014-01-01'  AND filter_2_id IN (20000, 20001)  AND filter_1_id IN ( 10000 )  order by tr.test_result_id ASC";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}\\-\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

O/P :

```
2013-01-01
2014-01-01
```